Linux automated SMB connection attempts: has my server been compromised?
We have a Linux server running CentOS 7. 
A few days ago,
we found out that it has started continuously attempting to connect to
a Windows server share via port 445 using a certain user's AD credentials. 
The user account info was given to me by the people
managing the other server (to which the connection is being attempted). 
Every 2-3 seconds there is a SYN_SENT request.
I am trying to find out what process is doing this,
but netstat and ss don't show any PID info for this. 
What can I do to find out the cause of this?
I went through this document (about Turla Penguin) and ran this command:
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +400k -size -5000k -exec md5sum {} \+ | grep -E '0994d9deb50352e76b0322f48ee576c6|14ecd5e6fc8e501037b54ca263896a11|19fbd8cbfb12482e8020a887d6427315|edf900cebb70c6d1fcab0234062bfc28|ea06b213d5924de65407e8931b1e4326|e079ec947d3d4dacb21e993b760a65dc|ad6731c123c4806f91e1327f35194722|b4587870ecf51e8ef67d98bb83bc4be7|7533ef5300263eec3a677b3f0636ae73'
which came up negative.

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. SYN_SENT is usually a message relating to the TCP-handshake at the beginning of a connection request (SYN / SYN-ACK / ACK). At this stage no data has been sent. You then say that the connection attempt is coming from a specific user account. Can you clarify your information sources, please, as I don't see how you can derive one from the other here.

@ChrisDavies - The user account info was given to me by the people managing the other server (to which the connection is being attempted). Since the issue was noticed we have blocked the IP of that server

If you really think this server has been compromised you should take it off the network. Now. Don't just block it. Prepare to rebuild it from scratch using known good sources. (This is all standard "compromise recovery" stuff.) But also look to see how it could have been compromised in the first place. Bear in mind that if it has been compromised it's quite possible that its own utilities have been altered so as to avoid reporting the compromise - you are highly likely not to find a file with that checksum using utilities running on the compromised machine.


A few days ago, we found out that it has started continuously attempting to connect to a Windows server share via port 445 using a certain user's AD credentials.

Have you been installing security patches? CentOS 7 is obsolete, and is anyway going to hit its end-of-life on June 30th this year.
Port 445 is the SMB service, and systems (unless you use a provisioning software such as Ansible or Puppet with a messed up configuration) don't spontaneously set them up to connect to a service on a remote host, especially using specific user credentials.

Every 2-3 seconds there is a SYN_SENT request.

This looks like a probe.  IIRC the Sasser worm does that.

I am trying to find out what process is doing this, but netstat and ss don't show any PID info for this.  What can I do to find out the cause of this?

In general, as @ChrisDavies said, you can't rely on tools on a machine which has been compromised to find out about the intrusion, because often the tools themselves have been replaced not to show the intrusion.
You should disconnect the machine from the network, then investigate to see if it was really compromised and in this case find the security hole which allowed the server to be hacked in the first place. Then wipe out the machine and do a clean reinstall with a modern OS.

How to do this investigation (once the system has been disconnected from the network)?
